# Passing custom form values to views

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to pass values from my custom form to my views.py . However, I can't seem to pass a value for each one of my multiselect options. When rendering there is only 1 charfield but multiple choices in the multichoiceselect. Any ideas? Will formsets be helpful here? Not sure how I'd implement it but any suggestions is appreciated. I'm new to django so explanations would also be helpful for me to learn!

models.py

```
class StateOption(models.Model):
   partstate = models.ForeignKey(State)
   partoption = models.ForeignKey(Option)
   relevantoutcome = models.ManyToManyField(Outcome, through='StateOptionOutcome')

class StateOptionOutcome(models.Model):
   stateoption = models.ForeignKey(StateOption)
   relevantoutcome = models.ForeignKey(Outcome)
   outcomevalue = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateStateOptionWithOutcomesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = StateOption
       exclude = ['partstate', 'partoption']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(UpdateStateOptionWithOutcomesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['relevantoutcome']=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Outcome.objects.all(),required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
       self.fields['outcomevalue']=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'30'}) #when rendering there is only 1 charfield. There should be the same amount of charfields as there are multiplechoicefields.
```

views.py

```
stateoption = get_object_or_404(StateOption, pk=stateoption_id)

if request.method == "POST":
    form = UpdateStateOptionWithOutcomesForm(request.POST, instance=stateoption)
    if form.is_valid():

       cd = form.cleaned_data
       outcomevalue = cd['outcomevalue']    

       for outcome_id in request.POST.getlist('relevantoutcome'):
           stateoption_outcome = StateOptionOutcome.objects.create(stateoption=stateoption, relevantoutcome_id=int(outcome_id), outcomevalue=outcomevalue)
```

template.html

```
 {% for field in form %}
    {{ field.label }}:
    {{ field }}
    {% if field.errors %}
        {{ field.errors|striptags }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update**

I can render an equal amount of charfields as choices now. But I am having trouble saving my values in the views.py since outcomevalue now contains multiple values. Any ideas on how to handle it?

```
if form.is_valid():

       cd = form.cleaned_data
       outcomevalue = cd['outcomevalue_1']   #only handles a specific outcomevalue        

       for outcome_id in request.POST.getlist('relevantoutcome'):
           stateoption_outcome = StateOptionOutcome.objects.create(stateoption=stateoption, relevantoutcome_id=int(outcome_id), outcomevalue=outcomevalue)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a loop to generate required amount of fields. Example:

```
outcome_qs = Outcome.objects.all()
self.fields['relevantoutcome'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=outcome_qs, required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
for outcome in outcome_qs:
    # Use Outcome primary key to easily match two fields in your view.
    self.fields['outcomevalue_%s' % outcome.pk] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'30'})
```

Comment: That does produce an equal number of outcomevalue fields for relevantoutcome. However, when I try to save the values I get a "outcomevalue" error in my views.py. Is it because my outcomevalue can only handle 1 value or is it because of the for loop?

Comment: You now have many fields `outcomevalue_*`. You need to handle them differently in you view.

Comment: As an alternative, is there a cleaner way that links outcomevalue to relevantoutcome in the custom form?