# efficient way to save custom form fields to database

Tags: django, django-forms

I am have trouble saving many fields into a database. I have a many 'outcomevalue_#' fields that get generated based on the number of outcomes I have. The user selects a subset of outcomes(relevantoutcomes) and enters the associated values. I'd like to save the associated values with the outcomes. So far I can only hardwire the field names which does not solve the problem.

views.py

```
stateoption = get_object_or_404(StateOption, pk=stateoption_id)

if request.method == "POST":
    form = UpdateStateOptionWithOutcomesForm(request.POST, instance=stateoption)
    if form.is_valid():

       cd = form.cleaned_data
       outcomevalue = cd['outcomevalue_1'] #hardwired. This needs to be generalized.        

       for outcome_id in request.POST.getlist('relevantoutcome'):
           stateoption_outcome = StateOptionOutcome.objects.create(stateoption=stateoption, relevantoutcome_id=int(outcome_id), outcomevalue=outcomevalue)
```

forms.py

```
class UpdateStateOptionWithOutcomesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = StateOption

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(UpdateStateOptionWithOutcomesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['relevantoutcome']=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Outcome.objects.all(),required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

       outcome_qs=Outcome.objects.all()
       for outcome in outcome_qs:
           self.fields['outcomevalue_%s' % outcome.pk] = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

**Update**

Here is my stripped down models.py

```
class StateOptionOutcome(models.Model):
   stateoption = models.ForeignKey(StateOption)
   relevantoutcome = models.ForeignKey(Outcome)
   outcomevalue = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

After some playing around I have something like:

```
 outcomelist = request.POST.getlist('relevantoutcome')
 for outcome_id in outcomelist:
       cd = form.cleaned_data
       outcomevalue = cd['outcomevalue_%s' % outcomelist[int(outcome_id)]]   

       stateoption_outcome = StateOptionOutcome.objects.create(stateoption=stateoption, relevantoutcome_id=int(outcome_id), outcomevalue=outcomevalue)
```

but get error:

```
list index out of range
```

because it is grabbing the values in the list rather than the index position

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you're trying to use a one-to-one relationship where there should be a one-to-many.  If you're going to have multiple Outcomes for one StateOption, may I suggest you use a many-to-many bridge table to link up which StateOption has which Outcome(s).  Then in that bridge table you can also store the associated value as an additional column for the appropriate StateOption/Outcome pair.

Comment: I do have that bridge table. I'll post it above. I was having trouble saving all the outcome values for outcomes. The code solves it but does not save all the values for all outcomes. For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494595/passing-custom-form-values-to-views

Answer (score 0):

Solve it by using:

```
outcomelist = request.POST.getlist('relevantoutcome')
       for i,outcome_id in enumerate(outcomelist):
           cd = form.cleaned_data
           outcomevalue = cd['outcomevalue_%s' % outcomelist[i]]   

           stateoption_outcome = StateOptionOutcome.objects.create(stateoption=stateoption, relevantoutcome_id=int(outcome_id), outcomevalue=outcomevalue)
```